# Inconsistency in Equality Comparison of Numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have read that there is no integer type in Javascript, only floating point double-precision (64 bit) type. I understand that because of that there will be some floating point arithmetic errors introduced even when comparing integers.

However, I don't understand why the three comparisons below would yield different results:

```
var aInt = 1 + 2;
var bInt = 3;
console.log("Comparing integers: ");
console.log(aInt === bInt); // Prints true

var aNum = 0.1 + 0.2;
var bNum = 0.3;
console.log("Comparing 0.1 + 0.2 === 0.3: ");
console.log(aNum === bNum); // Prints false

var aNum2 = 1.0 + 2.0;
var bNum2 = 3.0;
console.log("Comparing 1.0 + 2.0 === 3.0: ");
console.log(aNum2 === bNum2); // Prints true
```

I would have expected all the above comparisons to evaluate to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

At second example `aNum` returns `0.30000000000000004` , `bNum` returns `0.3`

To return `true` at strict equality comparison , try using `.toFixed()` , `Number()`

```js
var aNum = 0.1 + 0.2;
var bNum = 0.3;
console.log(Number(aNum.toFixed(1)), bNum);
console.log(Number(aNum.toFixed(1)) === bNum);
```

Comment: But then why doesn't 1.0 + 2.0 === 3.0 also return false?

Comment: `1.0` is converted to `1` , `2.0` is converted to `2` ; `3.0 === 3 // true`